# how to fix the error missing 2 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to program a small bot in python to be able to speak through a command, but I have a problem and it gives me an error when executing the command in discord, the error is this:

TypeError: send_message_from_webhook() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'keko' and 'msg'

and the code I'm using is this:

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="") 
bot.remove_command("help") 

@bot.event
async def on_message(message : discord.Message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    
    if 'prueba' in message.content.lower():
        await send_message_from_webhook(message)
        await message.delete()

async def send_message_from_webhook(message : discord.Message,  keko,  msg):
  
    
    webhook : discord.Webhook = await message.channel.create_webhook(name='haboo')
    #username = message.author.nick if message.author.nick else message.author.name
   
    
    
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name={keko}")
    skinhabbo = response.json()['figureString']
    

    await webhook.send(f"{msg}", username=f"{keko}", avatar_url=f"https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?size=m&figure={skinhabbo}&action=sit&direction=4&head_direction=4&gesture=std&size=m")
    await webhook.delete()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT ready")

bot.run("")
```

the bot would work as follows:

!prueba sefos hi

Can someone help me, thank you very much!

Comment: You are calling `send_message_from_webhook` with one argument and it expects three subjects. The error message clearly explained that. What is the question?

Comment: The command doesn't work for me, I don't know how to fix it

Comment: If you don't understand the basic Python syntax, like how to pass arguments to a function, I would suggest starting with the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial)

Comment: I think it would be something like "keko="
But I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I leave it

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="") 
bot.remove_command("help") 

@bot.command()
async def hablar(ctx, keko,*, msg):
    keko = f'{keko}' 
    msg = f'{msg}'
    await send_message_from_webhook(ctx.message, keko, msg)

async def send_message_from_webhook(message : discord.Message, keko, msg):
    webhook : discord.Webhook = await message.channel.create_webhook(name='haboo')
    
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name={keko}")
    skinhabbo = response.json()['figureString']
    
    await webhook.send(f"{msg}", username=f"{keko}", avatar_url=f"https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?size=m&figure={skinhabbo}&action=sit&direction=4&head_direction=4&gesture=std&size=m")
    await webhook.delete()
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")

bot.run("")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).